# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel

Estoy utilizando el método `updateOrCreate` para crear una factura si no esta creada y en caso de que lo este modificarla.

Pero siempre me salta este error y no veo ningun registro con el id especificado.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '580' for key 'PRIMARY'

Verifique en la base de datos y ese ID no existe.

**Mi controlador:**

```
$factura = new Factura;
$factura->created_at = $this->periodo;

$factura->updateOrCreate([
'cliente'           => $request->cliente,
'documento'         => $request->documento,
'tipo_factura'      => $this->tipo_factura,
```

**La migracion:**

```
Schema::create('facturas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('cliente')->nullable();
    $table->string('documento')->nullable(); 
    $table->string('tipo_factura')->nullable();
```

Comment: moviste los datos a mano (insertando cosas sin usar el autoincrement) y el autoincrement de la columna está intentando poner un valor que ya está

Comment: @Alfabravo si, pero en ningún momento toco la llave primaria. El valor que esta intentando poner el autoincrement no lo veo creado en la base de datos.

Comment: La BD no miente. Sin detalles de tu estructura de datos (la tabla destino) y una prueba replicable, la respuesta es: el autoincrement del campo (que es el que usa tu `create`) está chocando con datos que ya están

Comment: @Alfabravo he usado los métodos create y fill. No me dan este error, solo me pasa con el método updateOrCreate.

Comment: La pregunta sería: ¿por qué primero creas un objeto instanciado de tu modelo y luego intentas usarlo en el método `updateOrCreate`?, esa no es la sintaxis esperada, lee aqui https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: @BetaM gracias por responder. Mi error consistía en que estaba mas abajo del código estaba retornando de nuevo la instancia de mi factura, haciendo que se duplicara. Por esta razón el error en mi base de datos al tratar de guardar los dos registros idénticos.